# How to call dll file from main function?

Tags: c, visual-c++, dllexport

I have two function which process the string coming from main.cpp file and returns bool result.

I create dll file executing project with kmp.h and kmp.cpp files. [This files contains function defination which process string from main.cpp]

How can I use dll file generated from this execution for main.cpp file? so that I can directly pass string from main.cpp and dll file return me output as I have coded in kmp.cpp file?

Comment: Don't think in files/translation units. Think in classes, functions, etc. You can just import the header file of the library, then use the class as you would use in any case. The resulting object file, which is the output of the compilation of your program, will need to be linked against the DLL. I suggest you google "C++ compilation steps" so that you understand why and what happens and how this works.

Comment: "*... to be linked against the DLL.*" VC links against a so called Import Library not against the DLL itsself.

Answer (score 2):

You need to link your kmp library with your main program.  kmp.dll should not include a main because it is just a library, but a function that your main.cpp can call which performs the desired operation.  You will need to tell your IDE to link against your kmp library, and include your kmp header file at the top of your main.cpp.  you will be able to compile with just the header included but you will need to link your dll to actually use your executable.

Comment: thanks wolf -  Can you please tell me how to link dll with main.cpp?

Comment: How to link it depends on what environment you're using.  if its visual C++ in windows, I'm sorry to say I'm rather clueless...  this might be helpful, I just googled visual c++ link dll and this was first result:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yd93633(v=vs.71).aspx